# Most reliable adhesives to mount photos onto metal composite/ dibond sheets?

Tags: printing

I'm interested in mounting my photos onto sheets of aluminium dibond. After a lot of research it appears that there are 2 products being used: 3M positionable mounting adhesive and 3M Photo mount spray adhesives.

While I feel more inclined towards the latter, I want to be sure of it's quality as I will be selling these pictures.

Has anyone got any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

I have used the "positionable" adhesive which has a slow-bonding action allowing you to recover from "oops" situations.

Positionable is so-named as it slowly cures to be permanent after a few hours. It is NOT removable after it cures completely. It is archival and safe (non yellowing or bleeding) for artwork and photographs on light stock.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, I'm already aware of PMA, but since it has to be bought as an entire roll it proves to be rather expensive. I'm exploring other reliable alternatives. Will edit the question to reflect

Answer (score 1):

If you want the prints to be removable, I would suggest [3M ReMount](http://solutions.3m.co.uk/wps/portal/3M/en_GB/EUScotchbrand/Home/Products/ProductCatalogue/~/3M-ReMount-400-ml-Can?N=4335+3294174665+3294529196&rt=rud). The adhesive is the same as that used on Post It notes. It just comes in an aerosol can.

Comment: I mentioned I would be selling these prints, so removable is out of the question.

Comment: "Post It notes" and "most reliable" don't go together very well.

Comment: I'm sure you are both right. ReMount is a very useful, albeit little known, product, so I thought it worth mentioning.